# Use the primitive root $2$ mod $29$ to find all quadratic residues a mod 29 with $1 \leq a \leq 28$

Tags: number-theory

Use the primitive root $2$ mod $29$ to find all quadratic residues $a$ mod $29$ with $1 \leq a \leq 28$

I know that primitive roots are integers $x$ whose order is equal to $\varphi(x)$. But, in this question I can't tell if $2$ is the order or if I have to find the order of $2?$

But then how does that relate to finding all quadratic residues? My understanding is that the quadratic residues here would be integers less than $29$ that are perfect squares $\text{mod 29}$. So, an example would be $25$. But I don't recall what kind of relationship there is between primitive roots and perfect squares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $g$ is a primitive root mod $p$, then the quadratic residues mod $p$ are exactly $g^{2k}$ for $k=0,\dots,\frac{p-1}{2}$.

One direction is obvious. The other direction is [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion), which is also easy.

Comment: Oh, ok. it looks like i was on a totally "wrong" track altogether. Thank you! But what do you mean by the two directions? You mean directions of the proof for that if $g$ is a primitive root mod $p$ then the quadratic residues mod $p$ are exactly $g^{2k}$ for $k=0,...,\frac{p-1}{2}$?

Comment: @PBJ, yes, directions of the iff proof.